# install opencv on centos for java

Tags: java, linux, opencv, ant, centos

I'm trying to install opencv on my centos 8 server to be used by java program. I followed the instructions [here](https://www.howtoforge.com/how-to-install-opencv-on-centos-8/). after configuring opencv, I get the following result:

```
--   Java:
--     ant:                         NO
--     JNI:                         /usr/lib/jvm/java/include/usr/lib/jvm/java/include/linux/usr/lib/jvm/java/include
--     Java wrappers:               NO
--     Java tests:                  NO
```

I have already installed java on my server (by using `sudo dnf install java-11-openjdk-devel`, but I have not installed `ant`). in order to make opencv ready to be used by java, should ant and Java wrappers show YES? and how to correct my configurations in this case?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You need to install ANT and add it to the system path, which is used when building Java wrapper, and also set the OpenCV build_shared_libs = OFF, otherwise, the Java wrapper will not work.